# Rigify-armature won't attach to mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, rigify

I am a new Blender user.  I have a Genesis 3 character I created in DAZ.  I exported him as an fbx into Blender.  I followed a few tutorials and using rigify, I fit my bones onto my G3 character.  I created a rig using my armature, and it's not attaching to my G3 mesh.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am attaching a link to download to see what I've done here.  Thank you in advance!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iENa2NnRVvCUUQF3kzyXhcy90L7unsdp/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You attached the mesh to the "rig" armature but you should attach it to the "metarig".

Comment: will try that.  thank you.

Comment: Okay, I think i figured out the parenting, but I still don't have any movement with the mesh and the armature.  I saved my progress to the link above.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select your body mesh and go to the vertex groups, you will see that you have two "series" of vertex groups: one has been created by Rigify parenting (all thoose starting with the suffix "DEF"), the other created by another rig. The DEF vertex groups have no weights assignements (so they don't act), while the others do have weights, but they don't "talk" with rigify bones because they have non corresponding names.

There are three different ways of repair:

1) delete all "DEF" vertex groups, then rename all others vertex groups, i.e. "lindex3" shall be renamed "DEF-f_index.03.L" (I know, it's a pain".

2) rename the deforming bones of Rigify (the opposite, but another pain).

3) Delete all existing vertex groups and redo the weighting. If you want to use Automatic weighting you will have to temporarily detach the head from the body, because in the head region you will get the "Bone heat failing" error, and probably this is the reason why you did the parenting but only empty vertex groups were created.

BTW, it's correct to parent the mesh to "Rig", not "Metarig".

[image]

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you!!!  I'm on it!

Comment: If useful, please mark the answer as accepted (V sign).

Comment: I am choosing option #1.  I started changing the text in my vertex groups and am worried I'm naming them incorrectly.  Where could I find a list of the bones to make sure I'm naming them correctly in my vertex groups?

Comment: You'll have to copy them from a Rigify assignement, or from the names of Rigify's deforming bones, which are thoose on the last layer selected (in blue)  in my image, properties panel, Layers tab.